# python mask netcdf file with a shape file and dealing with LAT LONG in degree vs LAT LONG in meters

Tags: python, mask, python-xarray, shapefile

I am struggling to mask my netcdf dataset. I have managed to do something but not in the proper way.

Basically, I have a shape file and a netcdf dataset.

I read the shapefile as follow:

```py
import geopandas  as gpd
shp_noce       = gpd.read_file(shapefile_path)
```

which reads as:

```py
  DN                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((660074.143 5155942.267, 660172.884 5...
```

Then, I read the file as

```py
rain = xarray.open_dataset(ncfile_path)
```

and here is the results:

```py
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:              (DATE: 14245, x: 641, y: 643)
Coordinates:
  * DATE                 (DATE) datetime64[ns] 1980-01-01T12:00:00 ... 2018-1...
  * x                    (x) float64 6.058e+05 6.061e+05 ... 7.656e+05 7.658e+05
  * y                    (y) float64 5.06e+06 5.06e+06 ... 5.22e+06 5.22e+06
Data variables:
    transverse_mercator  |S1 ...
    precipitation        (DATE, y, x) float32 ...
Attributes:
    CDI:          Climate Data Interface version 1.9.9 (https://mpimet.mpg.de...
    Conventions:  CF-1.5
    Title:        Daily total precipitation Trentino-South Tyrol 250-meter re...
    Created on:   Fri Feb 26 21:30:51 2021
    history:      Fri Feb 26 23:31:30 2021: cdo -z zip -mergetime DAILYPCP_19...
    CDO:          Climate Data Operators version 1.9.9 (https://mpimet.mpg.de..
```

I have tried to follow some suggestions coming from other posts. First of all, I have tried  [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/masking-netcdf-time-series-data-from-shapefile-using-python), which is based on rioarray. This reads as:

```py
rain.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="lon", y_dim="lat", inplace=True)
```

this is the outcomes:

```py
    raise MissingSpatialDimensionError(

MissingSpatialDimensionError: x dimension (lon) not found.
```

As far I have understood, there could be a ploblem linking the shape file and the netcdf dataset due to the projection units.
So, following what reported in [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/354782/masking-netcdf-time-series-data-from-shapefile-using-python), I have done the following:

```
shp_noce.to_crs("epsg:3395")
```

However, I get the same error. I suppose because the field in the netcdf dataset are named  x and y.

What are you suggestions? should I rename the fields? should I "set_spatial_dims" as x and y?

Comment: Generally, please don't name specific users in your questions. Linking to the questions/answers you'd like to cite is fine. The goal here is to make each question stand on its own for other users with similar problems, so narrative elements about your progression through the problem shouldn't be included. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. What about changing the title as "python mask netcdf file with a shape file and dealing with Spherical vs Mercator" projections?

Comment: I think either one is fine. The guide to [ask] has tips on creating a good name but I think yours is fine. Another tip though - when asking about errors, be sure to include the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) - they're full of valuable debugging information. We need them to fully understand the problem, and I highly encourage you to read the linked article and get used to reading through your tracebacks too!

Comment: Also, it is bad practise to end by asking if you should do certain things without having done them. If you think something could be a solution, please try it before asking a question on SO.

Comment: also - I didn't catch this before. if your data is in a *transverse mercator*, that projection is [`epsg:9807`](https://epsg.io/9807-method), not `3395`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data and shapefile are in the same CRS (mercator), all you need to do is to tell rioxarray that your spatial dims are `x` and `y`.

```py
rain.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="x", y_dim="y", inplace=True)
```

See the rioxarray API documentation for [`ds.rio.set_spatial_dims`](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/html/rioxarray.html#rioxarray.rioxarray.XRasterBase.set_spatial_dims):

> **`set_spatial_dims`** *(x_dim: str, y_dim: str, inplace: bool = True)* → `Union[xarray.core.dataset.Dataset, xarray.core.dataarray.DataArray]`
>
> This sets the spatial dimensions of the dataset.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> - x_dim (str) – The name of the x dimension.
> - y_dim (str) – The name of the y dimension.
> - inplace (bool, optional) – If True, it will modify the dataframe in place. Otherwise it will return a modified copy.
>
> **Returns**
>
> - Dataset with spatial dimensions set.
>
> **Return type**
>
> - `xarray.Dataset | xarray.DataArray`

You told it to look for a dimension named "lon", and it's telling you that lon isn't found in the dataset. That's because the x dimension is named `"x"` :)